# What is the area of the region bounded by the equations $2y^2 - 9x = 36$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 36$ where $2y^2 - 9x \leq 36$ and $x^2 + y^2 \leq 36$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification, area

I am referring to this region:

[image]
The solution I made was this:

> To solve this problem, we have to solve for the function in terms of
> $y$.
> \begin{align*} x^{2} + y^{2} &\;=\; 36 \\  x^{2} &\;=\; 36 - y^{2} \\  x &\;=\; \pm\sqrt{36 - y^{2}} \end{align*}
>
> The one on the right side is what we need, hence we will take the
> equation with a positive sign. Solving for the ordinates of the
> intersections of both equations,
> \begin{align*} x^{2} + y^{2} &\;=\; 36 & 2y^{2} - 9x &\;=\; 36 \\  2x^{2} + 2y^{2} &\;=\; 72 & 2y^{2} &\;=\; 9x + 36 \end{align*}
> \begin{align*} 2x^{2} + 9x + 36 &\;=\; 72 \\  2x^{2} + 9x - 36 &\;=\; 0 \\  x &\;=\; \frac{-9\pm\sqrt{9^{2} - 4(2)(-36)}}{2(2)} \\  x &\;=\; \frac{-9\pm\sqrt{81 + 288}}{4} \\  x &\;=\; \frac{-9\pm\sqrt{369}}{4} \\ x &\;=\; \frac{-9\pm 3\sqrt{41}}{4} \end{align*}
>
> \begin{align*} 2y^{2} &\;=\; 9x + 36 \\  y^{2} &\;=\; \frac{9}{2}x + 18 \\  y^{2} &\;=\; \frac{9}{2}\left(\frac{-9 \pm 3\sqrt{41}}{4}\right) + 18 \\ y^{2} &\;=\; \frac{-81 \pm 27\sqrt{41}}{8} + 18 \end{align*}
>
> We will not solve for the one with negative sign as this will give a
> complex valued answer. \begin{align*}  y^{2} &\;=\; \frac{-81 + 18(8) + 27\sqrt{41}}{8} \\  y^{2} &\;=\; \frac{-81 + 144 + 27\sqrt{41}}{8} \\  y^{2} &\;=\; \frac{63 + 27\sqrt{41}}{8} \\  y &\;=\; \pm\sqrt{\frac{63 + 27\sqrt{41}}{8}} \end{align*}
>
> Solving for $x$ in the equation of the parabola,
> \begin{align*} 2y^{2} - 9x &\;=\; 36 \\  -9x &\;=\; -2y^{2} + 36 \\  x &\;=\; \frac{2}{9}y^{2} - 4 \end{align*}
>
> We will then solve for the definite integral
> \begin{gather*} \int_{-\sqrt{\frac{63 + 27\sqrt{41}}{8}}}^{\sqrt{\frac{63 + 27\sqrt{41}}{8}}} \left(\sqrt{36 - y^{2}} - \left(\frac{2}{9}y^{2} - 4\right)\right)\,dy \end{gather*}
>
> Solving for the indefinite integral,
> \begin{gather*} \int \left(\sqrt{36 - y^{2}} - \left(\frac{2}{9}y^{2} - 4\right)\right)\,dy \\  \int \sqrt{36 - y^{2}}\,dy - \int\frac{2}{9}y^{2}\,dy + \int 4\,dy \end{gather*}
>
> The last two integrals are $\frac{2}{27}y^{3} + 4y + C$. We'll solve
> for the first integral by parts. let $u = \sqrt{36 - y^{2}}$ and $dv = dy$. Then, $u = -\frac{y}{\sqrt{36 - y^{2}}}$ and $v = y$. Using the formula for the integration by parts, we get
> \begin{align*} \int \sqrt{36 - y^{2}}\,dy &\;=\; y\sqrt{36 - y^{2}} + \int \frac{-y^{2}}{\sqrt{36 - y^{2}}}\,dy + C\\  \int \sqrt{36 - y^{2}}\,dy &\;=\; y\sqrt{36 - y^{2}} + \int \frac{-36 + 36 - y^{2}}{\sqrt{36 - y^{2}}}\,dy + C\\  \int \sqrt{36 - y^{2}}\,dy &\;=\; y\sqrt{36 - y^{2}} + \int \frac{-36}{\sqrt{36 - y^{2}}}\,dy + \int \frac{36 - y^{2}}{\sqrt{36 - y^{2}}}\,dy + C\\  \int \sqrt{36 - y^{2}}\,dy &\;=\; y\sqrt{36 - y^{2}} - 36 \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{36 - y^{2}}} + \int\sqrt{36 - y^{2}}\,dy + C\\  2\int \sqrt{36 - y^{2}}\,dy &\;=\; y\sqrt{36 - y^{2}} - 36\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{6}\right) + C\\  \int\sqrt{36 - y^{2}}\,dy &\;=\; \frac{y\sqrt{36 - y^{2}}}{2} + 18\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{6}\right) + C \end{align*}
>
> Adding all terms, we have
> \begin{gather*} \frac{y\sqrt{36 - y^{2}}}{2} + 18\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{6}\right) + \frac{2}{27}y^{3} + 4y + C \end{gather*}
>
> Let this be $I$. Solving for the value of $I$ when $y = -\sqrt{\frac{63 + 27\sqrt{41}}{8}}$ and when
> \begin{align*} \begin{split} I_{1} &\;=\; \frac{1}{2}\left(-\sqrt{\frac{63 + 27\sqrt{41}}{8}}\right)\sqrt{36 - \left(-\sqrt{\frac{63 + 27\sqrt{41}}{8}}\right)^{2}} \\ &\;\phantom{=}\; + 18\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\cdot-\sqrt{\frac{63 + 27\sqrt{41}}{8}}\right) + \frac{2}{27}\left(-\sqrt{\frac{63 + 27\sqrt{41}}{8}}\right)^{3} + 4\left(-\sqrt{\frac{63 + 27\sqrt{41}}{8}}\right)\end{split} \\  \begin{split} I_{2} &\;=\; \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{\frac{63 + 27\sqrt{41}}{8}}\right)\sqrt{36 - \left(\sqrt{\frac{63 + 27\sqrt{41}}{8}}\right)^{2}} \\ &\;\phantom{=}\; + 18\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{63 + 27\sqrt{41}}{8}}\right) + \frac{2}{27}\left(-\sqrt{\frac{63 + 27\sqrt{41}}{8}}\right)^{3} + 4\left(\sqrt{\frac{63 + 27\sqrt{41}}{8}}\right)\end{split} \end{align*}
>
> Both $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ are too complicated to be solved in this
> paper. Using WolframAlpha, we get that
> \begin{align*} I_{2} - I_{1} &\;=\; 2\sqrt{\frac{4354063}{10368} + \frac{228889\sqrt{41}}{3456}} + 36\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{7}{32} + \frac{3\sqrt{41}}{32}}\right) \end{align*}
>
> Therefore, the area of the  region bounded by $2y^{2} - 9x = 36$ and $x^{2} + y^{2} = 36$ is $$2\sqrt{\frac{4354063}{10368} + \frac{228889\sqrt{41}}{3456}} + 36\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{7}{32} + \frac{3\sqrt{41}}{32}}\right).$$

However, when I checked through Desmos, the answer that is approximately $74.3106147858$. Where did I go wrong in my solution, please?

Comment: I think you have two regions. Your equations do not have inequality to clarify which region you are interested in.

Comment: No you do not have but you should have. Have you drawn both equations?

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot which one. I'll include an image.

Comment: Based on your diagram, please state the region as $2y^2 - 9x \leq  36, x^2 + y^2 \leq 36$.

Comment: I think it's easier to integrate over $x$, and changing the function where they intersect. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*int_%28-4%29%5E%283*sqrt%2841%29-9%29%2F4+sqrt%28%2836%2B9x%29%2F2%29dx%2B2*int_%28%283*sqrt%2841%29-9%29%2F4%29%5E6+sqrt%2836-x%5E2%29dx. If you put one integral at a time wolfram gives you a closed form.

Comment: Your mistake: You write integral of one of the terms as $\frac{2}{27}y^{3} + 4y + C$. No. It should be $ - \frac{2}{27}y^{3} + 4y + C$

Comment: Fix that and check if you get the correct answer but I would only say that you could have simplified your working to some extent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area is given by the integral $$I=\int_{-a}^a\left(\sqrt{36-x^2}-\frac29x^2+4\right)\,dx=2\left(\frac{a\sqrt{36-a^2}}2+18\sin^{-1}\frac a6-\frac2{27}a^3+4a\right)$$ where $a=\sqrt{(63+27\sqrt{41})/8}$. In your attempt, you have calculated all the indefinite integrals correctly, so some of the simplification after substituting $a$ must have gone wrong. Most likely it is a case of an accidental typo in the search query as you used Wolfram|Alpha. In addition, as @MathLover has pointed out, you made a sign error in the $2a^3/27$ term.

With such an unpleasant nested radical, it is not worth the simplification so it suffices to stop at the expression above.

If you really want to continue, here is a complete manual calculation (why did I even do this?). Note that \begin{align}a\sqrt{36-a^2}&=\sqrt{\frac{63+27\sqrt{41}}8}\sqrt{36-\frac{63+27\sqrt{41}}8}\\&=\frac18\sqrt{(63+27\sqrt{41})(225-27\sqrt{41})}\\&=\frac18\sqrt{-15714+4374\sqrt{41}}.\end{align} Further, the binomial theorem gives \begin{align}a^3&=\sqrt{\frac{(63+27\sqrt{41})^3}{8^3}}=\frac18\sqrt{\frac{1474767+282123\sqrt{41}}2}\end{align} so that \begin{align}I&=\small\sqrt{\frac{-7857+2187\sqrt{41}}{32}}+36\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{7+3\sqrt{41}}{32}}-\sqrt{\frac{2023+387\sqrt{41}}8}+\sqrt{504+216\sqrt{41}}\\&=36\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{7+3\sqrt{41}}{32}}+\sqrt{a_1+b_1\sqrt{41}}-\sqrt{a_2+b_2\sqrt{41}}+\sqrt{a_3+b_3\sqrt{41}}\end{align} where $a_1=-7857/32$, $b_1=2187/32$, $a_2=2023/8$, $b_2=387/8$, $a_3=504$ and $b=216$. Letting $$\sqrt{a_1+b_1\sqrt{41}}-\sqrt{a_2+b_2\sqrt{41}}=\sqrt{a_4+b_4\sqrt{41}}$$ for some real $a_4,b_4$, we obtain $$(a_1+a_2-a_4+(b_1+b_2-b_4)\sqrt{41})^2=4(a_1+b_1\sqrt{41})(a_2+b_2\sqrt{41}).$$ Equating terms gives \begin{align}(a_1+a_2-a_4)^2+41(b_1+b_2-b_4)^2&=4(a_1a_2+41b_1b_2)\\(a_1+a_2-a_4)(b_1+b_2-b_4)&=2(a_1b_2+a_2b_1).\end{align} This gives the quadratic $$(a_1+a_2-a_4)^2+\frac{4\cdot41(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)^2}{(a_1+a_2-a_4)^2}=4(a_1a_2+41b_1b_2)$$ so that \begin{align}(a_1+a_2-a_4)^2&=\frac{4(a_1a_2+41b_1b_2)\pm\sqrt{16(a_1a_2+41b_1b_2)^2-16\cdot41(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)^2}}2\\\frac{(a_1+a_2-a_4)^2}2&=a_1a_2+41b_1b_2\pm\sqrt{(a_1a_2+41b_1b_2)^2-41(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)^2}.\end{align} This gives \begin{align}\frac{\left(\frac{235}{32}-a_4\right)^2}2=\frac{9403209}{128}\pm64800\implies a_4=\frac{235}{32}\pm\sqrt{\frac{9403209}{64}\pm129600}\end{align} and $$b_4=\frac{3735}{32}-\frac{58320}{\pm\sqrt{\frac{9403209}{64}\pm129600}}.$$ Checking all four permutations of signs, we find that both must be negative, so that the sum simplifies to $$\sqrt{\frac{-7857+2187\sqrt{41}}{32}}-\sqrt{\frac{2023+387\sqrt{41}}8}=-\sqrt{\frac{-3977+1107\sqrt{41}}{32}}.$$ Thus $$I=36\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{7+3\sqrt{41}}{32}}+\sqrt{a_3+b_3\sqrt{41}}-\sqrt{a_5+b_5\sqrt{41}}$$ where $a_5=-3977/32$ and $b_5=1107/32$. Repeating the tedious process above yields $$\sqrt{a_3+b_3\sqrt{41}}-\sqrt{a_5+b_5\sqrt{41}}=\sqrt{\frac{16087+3123\sqrt{41}}{32}}.$$ In conclusion, we obtain \begin{align}I&=36\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{7+3\sqrt{41}}{32}}+\sqrt{\frac{16807+3123\sqrt{41}}{32}}\approx74.3\\&\ne36\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{7+3\sqrt{41}}{32}}+2\sqrt{\frac{4354063}{10368} + \frac{228889\sqrt{41}}{3456}}\approx98.8.\end{align}

Comment: I think I already have done that, since $18\sin^{-1}\frac{a}{6}$ became $36\sin^{-1}\frac{a}{6}$.

Comment: @soupless Yes I've just realised that at the same time. See revised (you have probably simply made a typo).

Comment: Can I ask what the correct answer should be? I also doubted my query in Wolfram|Alpha because it seems like a complicated expression to type.

Comment: See revised. I need a break.

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to swap $X$ and $Y$-axis
and consider functions

\begin{align}
f_t(y)&=\sqrt{36-y^2}
,\\
f_b(y)&=-\sqrt{36-y^2}
,\\
f_p(y)&=\tfrac29\,y^2-4
,
\end{align}
which is obviously the circle-parabola intersection.
[image]

$y$-coordinates of two points of their intersection can be found as

\begin{align} 
y_1&=-\tfrac34\sqrt{14+6\sqrt{41}}
,\\
y_2&=\tfrac34\sqrt{14+6\sqrt{41}}
.
\end{align}

There are actually two regions,
let's consider the upper one.
There ia also a symmetry we can consider, so the sought area would be

\begin{align} 
A&=2\int_0^{y_2}(f_t(y)-f_p(y)) \,dy
\\
&=
2\int_0^{y_2}(\sqrt{36-y^2}-(\tfrac29\,y^2-4)) \,dy
\\
&=
\left.y\sqrt{36-y^2}+36\arcsin(\tfrac16\,y)
-\tfrac4{27}\,y^3+8y\right|_{y=0}^{\tfrac34\sqrt{14+6\sqrt{41}}}
\\
&=
\tfrac18\sqrt{32174+6246\sqrt{41}}
+36\arcsin(\tfrac18\sqrt{14+6\sqrt{41}})
\\
&\approx 74.31061478582
.
\end{align}